# Why is Cognito no longer an Authorizer option in the API gateway UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In API Gateway, **Cognito** was previously an Authorizer option. Indeed, the AWS Developer Documentation still refers to its use. However, the new UI does not have it as an option. We are concerned about switching back to the old UI and continuing is use if it is a deprecated feature.

Q: Is the use of Cognito as an authorizer still appropriate, even though it is not a choice in the new UI?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cognito option is only shown in REST APIs and not for HTTP APIs

For HTTP APIs, you can use Amazon Cognito as a JWT issuer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html